# UPDATE within a table from table name saved in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem, but I'm sure it s not really complicated.

It's just hard to find the key word to describe the problem and find a solution

I want to update a column in a table using parameters from this table for a query on an other table.

Example : I have Header + 2 lines

```
IDSOURCE, IDCIBLE, IDENTIFIANT, TABLE_CIBLE, NOM_ATTRIBUT, NOM_CHAMP_IDENTTIFIANT, NOM_CIBLE 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
DMT_1000, DMT_1000, 1000, [dictionnaire].[dbo].[TABLE_CHAMPS_DATAMART], NOM_CHAMP_DMT, IDENTIFIANT_CHAMP_DATAMART, NULL 
DMT_1001, DMT_1001, 1001, [dictionnaire].[dbo].[TABLE_CHAMPS_DATAMART], NOM_CHAMP_DMT, IDENTIFIANT_CHAMP_DATAMART, NULL
```

And I want to update the last column of each line with something like :

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.NOM_CIBLE = SELECT table.NOM_ATTRIBUT FROM table.TABLE_CIBLE WHERE table.NOM_CHAMP_IDENTTIFIANT = table.IDCIBLE
FROM
    Table
```

Don't know if it s clear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: key words are 'update from select' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: What is the other table here?

Comment: the other table is contained in the TABLE_CIBLE attribute but it can change from 1 line to an other

Comment: @Hystic: You might need to run a cursor and get the value from table saved in the column and use that in dynamic sql

Comment: You will need to resort to [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to be able to _dynamically_ change table name.

Comment: do you have two tables or change table name dynamically ah?

Comment: I have 1 table wich must be filled with the information of 5 other table

Comment: `TABLE_CIBLE` its have 5 other table names or other table values

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like situation where you could use a cursor. Check out this StackOverflow question [How to update a column fetched by a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470056/how-to-update-a-column-fetched-by-a-cursor-in-tsql)